# Por que não está mostrando o login salvo no LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, apache-cordova, localstorage

Estou criando um app híbrido com cordova, e quero que ao usuário efetuar o primeiro login, ele permaneça logado direto. Se ele sair do app por exemplo, e entrar novamente, ele não precisará efetuar um novo login. Estou usando o código abaixo até o momento, o valor é armazenado no LocalStorage, mais não é exibido no input após atualizar o mesmo.

index.html

```
<h1 style="font-size: 1.8em;">Login</h1>
                <div class="alert alert-danger text-center" id="message"></div>
                <div>
                    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="txt_username" name="txt_username" placeholder="Usuário">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control mt-2" id="txt_pwd" name="txt_pwd" placeholder="Senha"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="button" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-danger btn-block mt-3" name="but_submit" id="but_submit" />
                </div>
```

index.js

```
var login = document.getElementById('txt_username');

login.addEventListener('input', (e)=>{

window.localStorage.setItem('login', login.value);

var cat = window.localStorage.getItem('login');

$("#txt_username").val(cat);
})
```

Comment: O `document.getElementById('txt_username').value();` vai pegar o valor do elemento no momento em que ele foi executado. Se a página foi carregada neste instante e o `#txt_username` tiver com valor vazio, será salvo o valor de vazio. Usa o proprio inspecionar elemento e veja no LocalStorage o valor salvo, mesmo no mobile é possível fazer isso.

Comment: Como faria para pegar o valor no momento em que ele é digitado?

Comment: Continua o mesmo problema, fiz o seguinte teste  `var login = "Olá" `; e ele exibe normalmente.

Comment: @AndréSantos pode fazer isso usando o [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener), existe o evento de [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) e de [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event). Então, ao ser digitado/modificado você armazena o valor.

Comment: Desculpem mais nunca usei addEventListener, poderia me dar um exemplo de como ficaria meu código com ele?

Comment: @AugustoVasques entendo mais pretendo passar depois para o sqlite. Por enquanto o LocalStorage quebraria um galho.

Comment: A não funcionou :(  Adicionei uma imagem a pergunta de como ficou meu código final, mais não funcionou

Comment: Se eu tirar `value` vai dar erro `[object HTMLInputElement]`

Comment: há não tá salvando mesmo assim

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque um [mcve] contendo o html e código que está tentando usar o localStorage.

Comment: Eu não entendo, não está armazenando no LocalStorage o valor, mais como eu disse se eu fizer `var login = "Olá"` ele armazena normalmente

Comment: Modifiquei a pergunta, adicionei as sugestões e o HTML

Comment: O código **funciona perfeitamente**. Veja: https://repl.it/repls/EquatorialExtrasmallCircles o problema é que você está tentando atualiza um input com um valor que ela já contém e a mudança é visualmente redundante.

Comment: Sim ele pega o valor, mais ao atualizar a página o valor não é exibido no input

Comment: Mas você não programou para isso!!! Poxa, tem que colocar essa funcionalidade de recuperar os dados do localStorage  no evento `load` da página. No evento `input` você armazena os dados no `load` você recupera.

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu atualizei a pergunta quando vc pediu, e coloquei esse detalhe :)

Answer (score 1):

No `onload` da página você tem que chamar uma função para verificar se há alguma coisa no `localStorage`, se houver, ele insere no `input`, caso não, o `input` continua limpo.

Dei uma olhada rápida na documentação do cordova e achei [isso aqui](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html). Acho que pode te ajudar.

Fiz um código com js puro para você dar uma olhada.

```js
const login = document.getElementById('txt_username');

login.addEventListener('input', (e)=>{
  window.localStorage.setItem('login', login.value);
  const cat = window.localStorage.getItem('login');
  login.val(cat);
});

window.onload = () => {
  const cat = window.localStorage.getItem('login');
  if (cat) {
    login.value = cat
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 style="font-size: 1.8em;">Login</h1>
<div class="alert alert-danger text-center" id="message"></div>
<div>
  <input type="name" class="form-control" id="txt_username" name="txt_username" placeholder="Usuário">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="password" class="form-control mt-2" id="txt_pwd" name="txt_pwd" placeholder="Senha"/>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-danger btn-block mt-3" name="but_submit" id="but_submit" />
</div>
```